# Convert CGImage? to an Image I can show in my view (swiftUI)

Tags: ios, swiftui, qr-code, apple-watch, watchos

I am working with EFQRCode library and am trying to generate a QR-code on my apple watch.
The result of `EFQRCode.generate(for: "test")`
is a **CGImage**. If I print the line above I get something like this:

> Optional(<CGImage 0x16db3160> (DP)
> <<CGColorSpace 0x16d5c750> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)>
> width = 600, height = 600, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 2400
> kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGImageByteOrder32Little  | kCGImagePixelFormatPacked
> is mask? No, has masking color? No, has soft mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes)

Is there a way of turning this into an image I can show on the watch?
Or are there any other ways of creating a QR-code on the apple-watch. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you want to show it? As a UIImage? Then wrap the CGImage in a UIImage. Unclear what the issue is here.

Comment: I just need to show it. So I tried to wrap the CGImage in a UIImage. Now I get the error-message: "Referencing static method 'buildBlock' on 'Optional' requires that 'UIImage' conform to 'View'" and "Static method 'buildBlock' requires that 'UIImage' conform to 'View'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to create `Image` via `UIImage` created with `CGImage`, like

```
if let cgImage = EFQRCode.generate(for: "test") {
    Image(uiImage: UIImage(cgImage: cgImage))
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I have been searching for a solution the last few hours. :)